# Serving "less trusted" content on the same domain

Tags: content-security-policy, same-origin-policy

Let's say we run a web app at "example.org".  It uses cookies for user authentication.

Our website also has a blog at "example.org/blog", hosted by a third party.  Our load balancer routes all requests to "/blog" (and subpaths) to our blog host's servers.  We don't *distrust* them, but we'd prefer if security issues with the blog host can't affect our primary web app.

Here are the security concerns I'm aware of, along with possible solutions.

1. The requests to the blog host will contain our user's cookies.

   - Solution: Have the load balancer strip cookies before forwarding requests to the blog host.
2. An XSS on the blog allows the attacker to inject JS and read the cookie.

   - Solution: Use "HTTP-only" cookies.
3. An XSS on the blog allows the attacker to inject JS and make an AJAX request to "example.org" with the user's cookies.  Because of the same origin policy, the browser allows the attacker's JS to read the response.

   - Solution: Have the load balancer add some Content-Security-Policy to the blog responses?  What's the right policy to set?
   - Solution: Suborigins ([link](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-suborigins/)) looks nice, but we can't depend on browser support yet.

Is there a way to safely host the blog on the same domain?

Comment: Why not just put them under different subdomains?

Comment: @multithr3at3d: That's our backup plan.  Using the same domain has some advantages, so I'm trying to see if that's feasible first.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way do safely host the blog on the same domain?

No. The Same Origin Policy is enforced on the client side. The SOP assumes that all content from the same origin can trust and interact with each other. There is currently no way to reliably fix this assumption on the server side. Note that  CSP is not sufficiently implemented by all relevant browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could add *web application firewall* (WAF) functionalities on your load balancer. In addition to protecting the web application from unexpected user input, there could be rules designed to protect the user from unexpected output from the 3rd party backend server.